# Collatz sequence length

Tags: javascript, debugging, collatz

I'm trying to find the longest [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) sequence for numbers less than, say 100, but there's a bug that I can't find, that makes my code crash:

```
var longest=0; //holds the biggest m
var m=0; //count of steps for at given n

//in the following, the counter var starts the sequence by giving it's
//value to n, then n loops the sequence. When loop finishes as n == 1, new 
//number is looped (n = counter++)

for(var counter = 2; counter <100; counter++){
var n = counter;
while(n!= 1){   //when n==1, loop should stop

            if(n%2 == 0){
                n = even(n);
                m++;
            }
                if(n%2 != 0){   
                n = odd(n);
                m++ ;
            }               
        }   

    if(m>longest){
        longest = m;
    }
    m = 0; // resets m counter of steps in loop for new number to loop
}
function even(k){
    return k/2;
}
function odd(k){
    return 3*k+1;
}
```

Why is my code crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counter you should consider using `n` inside the while loop and also you need to use `if-else` instead of `if-if`.

```
        if(n%2 == 0){
            n = even(n);
            m++;
        }
        else{ 
            n = odd(n);
            m++ ;
        }
```

because it is the `n` that will change in while loop not counter. And you are basically resetting value of `n` before while loop. So you should check the running value of `n`.

Collatz sequence simply in each step do perform operation based on it's parity.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected that. It's still crashing though.

Comment: @ahhsad.: Did you run it and understood where it went wrong?